# python noob having troubles sending google voice text

Tags: python, sms, beautifulsoup, google-voice

I'm writing a simple little script to send me a text message when the Ultra Music Festival early bird tickets go on sale so I can snatch them up. When I came to writing this I figured python would be a quick way to achieve my goal. What I do is collect the links and then count them and determine if there is a change and send a google voice text message to a couple numbers. Here is my code ran against stackoverflow.

```
from googlevoice import Voice
from googlevoice.util import input
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from time import sleep
import urllib2
from array import *

#define login details
email = 'example@gmail.com'
password = 'password'
url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions'

def send_message(var_text):
    voice = Voice()
    voice.login(email, password)

    phoneNumber = array('L',[9998675309, 9998675309])   
    for i in phoneNumber:
        voice.send_sms(i, var_text)

#init
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))

link_count = len(soup)

#start the loop
var = 1
while var == 1 :  # This constructs an infinite loop
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
    if link_count != len(soup): 
        string = str('Link Count Changed\n\nSite:\n' + url + '\nPrev:\n' + str(link_count) + '\nNew:\n' + str(len(soup)))
        send_message(string)
        print (string)
        link_count = len(soup)
        sleep(10)
        pass
    else:
        print('Number of links ('+ str(link_count) + ') has not changed, going to sleep now.') 
        sleep(10)
        pass
print "Good bye!"
```

Here is the error I keep getting (only seems to happen when sending to more then one number)

```
doesn't work array('L',[9998675309, 9998675309])
works array('L',[9998675309])
```

ERROR:

```
bash-3.2# python gvsendalert.py 
Number of links (195) has not changed, going to sleep now.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gvsendalert.py", line 32, in <module>
    send_message(string)
  File "gvsendalert.py", line 19, in send_message
    voice.send_sms(i, var_text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googlevoice/voice.py", line 151, in send_sms
    self.__validate_special_page('sms', {'phoneNumber': phoneNumber, 'text': text})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googlevoice/voice.py", line 225, in __validate_special_page
    load_and_validate(self.__do_special_page(page, data))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googlevoice/util.py", line 65, in load_and_validate
    validate_response(loads(response.read()))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googlevoice/util.py", line 59, in validate_response
    raise ValidationError('There was a problem with GV: %s' % response)
googlevoice.util.ValidationError: There was a problem with GV: {u'data': {u'code': 58}, u'ok': False}
```

Ok I've taken into consideration what some of you have posted and come out with this. For the number array sending my google voice number twice it will send 2 messages. If I put my friends number as the second it breaks it. Could this be because my friends number is not a google voice number? I have been able to send messages to this number using Google Voice and some other 3rd party iPhone applications so I would think the python module would work the same way.

Here is my 2nd Revision Code:

```
def send_message(var_text):
    voice = Voice()
    voice.login(email, password)

    phoneNumber = ['myrealgooglenumber', 'myfriendsactualphonenumber']  
    for i in phoneNumber:
        print( str('sending to: ') + str(i))
        voice.send_sms(str(i), str(var_text))
        sleep(5)

#init
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))

link_count = len(soup)

#start the loop
var = 1
while var == 1 :  # This constructs an infinite loop
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
    if link_count != len(soup): 
        string = ('Link Count Changed\n\nSite:\n{0}\nPrev:\n{1}\nNew:\n{2}').format(url, link_count, len(soup))     
        send_message(string)        
        link_count = len(soup)
        print (string)
        sleep(10)
        pass
    else:
        string = ('Number of links ({0}) has not changed, going to sleep now.').format(str(link_count))
        print(string) 
        sleep(10)
        pass
print "Good bye!"
```

Have tested with 2 google voice numbers and it works. Still doesn't work with non google voice numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Google may have a timer to prevent you sending too many SMS messages back to back.

Perhaps you could try changing your loop to something like:

```
for i in phoneNumber:
    voice.send_sms(i, var_text)
    sleep(5)
```

One other thought, does it work better if you use 2 different phone numbers?

Comment: it only works with my google voice number twice with the second revision code, but throws the error when I put my friends in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using ints for the phone numbers.

Phone numbers are *not* true numbers.

Try strings instead:

```
phoneNumber = ['9998675309', '9998675309']
```

Also, on a style note, have a look at string formatting:

```
string = 'Link Count Changed\n\nSite:\n{0}\nPrev:\n{1}\nNew:\n{2}').format(url, link_count, len(soup))
```

Comment: I had no idea you could format the string like that. Thanks for the advices. So much cleaner to read.